# Can I remove this wall?

Tags: walls, removal, load-bearing

This is the plan of the house I'm living in, and I'm thinking of making some changes. The measurements are in `cm`. The construction brick, circa 1980. It has only ground and first floor.

Before I'll go forward and talk with a construction team, I'm curious to know if I can continue planning considering the following two questions:

A) theoretically is possible to remove the wall marked with green?
B) is it possible to move the door from blue rectangle position to the orange one?

[image]

Comment: Which way do the joists run?

Comment: That looks awfully like a centerline wall from the floor plan. I agree first questions are whether it's parallel or orthogonal to the joists and what's under it. Load bearing walls _can_ be opened, but it takes an engineer to day how and I'd leave the actual work to an (insured!) pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based solely on typical building practices and my assumptions about your home^, the green wall is likely not load-bearing and can be removed.

The doorways can almost certainly be exchanged, providing that you implement the same structural header arrangement that the existing door has now. It's unlikely that there's a post in that location, though there may be plumbing, ducting, or wiring to consider.

^ *That the roof system runs across the narrow dimension of the home, and that floor joists rest on the center wall.*